# StopWatch Function in Python

Tags: python, timer

I'm pretty new to python and I spent a couple hours on a simple project that involves prime numbers. I need to interpret a timer to count the delay of how long it takes to find x amount of prime numbers and give me back that delay in the form of a message box. Here is what I have so far for the project and it works perfectly fine.

```
import time
import ctypes

lower = 1
upper = 25000000
z = 1
while z < 1000:

if z == 100:
    break
for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                 break
        else:
             z += 1
             print(z,  ": ", num)
```

Comment: You're looking for [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) I think.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, you want to calculate how much time you need to calculate `z` number of prime number.

You can simply start a timer at the beginning of the program and subtract it at the end.

```
import time

def is_prime(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3, x, 2):
        if x%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

start_time = time.time()
z = 1
i=3
while True:
    if z == 3000:
        break
    if is_prime(i):
        z += 1
    i += 1

delay = time.time() - start_time

print('Delay: ', delay)
```

`Delay:  1.3431673049926758`

Comment: This works perfectly for what I was looking for. Thank you so much!